# Extracting unique URLs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, web-scraping, text-mining

I would like to extract entire unique url items in my list in order to move on a web scraping project. Although I have huge list of URLs on my side, I would like to generate here minimalist scenario to explain main issue on my side. Assume that my list is like that:

```
url_list = ["https://www.ox.ac.uk/",
            "http://www.ox.ac.uk/",
            "https://www.ox.ac.uk",
            "http://www.ox.ac.uk",
            "https://www.ox.ac.uk/index.php",
            "https://www.ox.ac.uk/index.html",
            "http://www.ox.ac.uk/index.php",
            "http://www.ox.ac.uk/index.html",
            "www.ox.ac.uk/",
            "ox.ac.uk",
            "https://www.ox.ac.uk/research"        
            ]
def ExtractUniqueUrls(urls):
    pass

ExtractUniqueUrls(url_list)
```

For the minimalist scenario, I am expecting there are only two unique urls which are "https://www.ox.ac.uk" and "https://www.ox.ac.uk/research". Although each url element have some differences such as "**http**", "**https**", with ending "**/**", without ending "**/**", **index.php**, **index.html**; they are all pointing exactly the same web page. There might be some other possibilities which I already missed them (Please remember them if you catch any). Anyway, what is the proper and efficient way to handle this issue using Python 3?

I am not looking for a hard-coded solution like focusing on each case individually. For instance, I do not want to manually check whether the url has "/" at the end or not. Possibly there is a much better solution with other packages such as urllib? For that reason, I looked the method of urllib.parse, but I could not come up a proper solution so far.
Thanks

**Edit**: I added one more example into my list at the end in order to explain in a better way. Otherwise, you might assume that I am looking for the root url, but this not the case at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By only following all cases you've reveiled:

```
url_list = ["https://www.ox.ac.uk/",
            "http://www.ox.ac.uk/",
            "https://www.ox.ac.uk",
            "http://www.ox.ac.uk",
            "https://www.ox.ac.uk/index.php",
            "https://www.ox.ac.uk/index.html",
            "http://www.ox.ac.uk/index.php",
            "http://www.ox.ac.uk/index.html",
            "www.ox.ac.uk/",
            "ox.ac.uk",
            "ox.ac.uk/research",
            "ox.ac.uk/index.php?12"]

def url_strip_gen(source: list):
    replace_dict = {".php": "", ".html": "", "http://": "", "https://": ""}

    for url in source:
        for key, val in replace_dict.items():
            url = url.replace(key, val, 1)
        url = url.rstrip('/')

        yield url[4:] if url.startswith("www.") else url


print(set(url_strip_gen(url_list)))
```

```
{'ox.ac.uk/index?12', 'ox.ac.uk/index', 'ox.ac.uk/research', 'ox.ac.uk'}
```

This won't cover case if url contains `.html` like `www.htmlsomething`, in that case it can be compensated with `urlparse` as it stores path and url separately like below:

```py
>>> import pprint
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> a = urlparse("http://ox.ac.uk/index.php?12")
>>> pprint.pprint(a)
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='ox.ac.uk', path='/index.php', params='', query='12', fragment='')
```

However, if without scheme:

```py
>>> a = urlparse("ox.ac.uk/index.php?12")
>>> pprint.pprint(a)
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='ox.ac.uk/index.php', params='', query='12', fragment='')
```

All host goes to `path` attribute.

To compensate this we either need to remove scheme and add one for all or check if url starts with scheme else add one. Prior is easier to implement.

```
replace_dict = {"http://": "", "https://": ""}

    for url in source:
        # Unify scheme to HTTP
        for key, val in replace_dict.items():
            url = url.replace(key, val, 1)

        url = "http://" + (url[4:] if url.startswith("www.") else url)
        parsed = urlparse(url)
```

With this you are guaranteed to get separate control of each sections for your url via `urlparse`. However as you do not specified which parameter should be considered for url to be *unique* enough, I'll leave that task to you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This is really problematic because it extracts "ox.ac.uk/researc" for the "ox.ac.uk/research". I do not think so this can be a complete solution at all. What do you think ?

Comment: The answer I read earlier was different, wasn't it ? This looks better than the previous one but still does not point what I mean really. For instance, it cannot capture "http://www.ox.ac.uk/index.php?12" as a different url. Or it wrongly summarise http://www.ox.ac.uk/test.html as http://www.ox.ac.uk/test. I think, there should be package solution instead of built-in functions because there are enormous amount of possibilities, arent they ?

Comment: I agree, but didn't even think there would be ```.php?12``` sort of things at first place, if that's the case - you should update and specify all possible cases you could encounter at your best.

Comment: You are right but if I place entire scenarios, it will be quite big set of examples. I tried to minimise the set but I have explained the main point. I expect to see a package for this purpose instead of builtin solutions because it is quite difficult to think entire cases when you are answering just this question. Thanks again

Comment: How about uploading sources to pastebin sorta sites? That would help others a lot you know, if that's not sensitive ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty attempt:

```
def extract_unique_urls(url_list):

    unique_urls = []
    for url in url_list:
        # Removing the 'https://' etc. part
        if url.find('//') > -1:
            url = url.split('//')[1]
        # Removing the 'www.' part
        url = url.replace('www.', '')
        # Removing trailing '/'
        url = url.rstrip('/')
        # If not root url then inspect the last part of the url
        if url.find('/') > -1:
            # Extracting the last part
            last_part = url.split('/')[-1]
            # Deciding if to keep the last part (no if '.' in it)
            if last_part.find('.') > -1:
                # If no to keep: Removing last part and getting rid of
                # trailing '/'
                url = '/'.join(url.split('/')[:-1]).rstrip('/')
        # Append if not already in list
        if url not in unique_urls:
            unique_urls.append(url)

    # Sorting for the fun of it
    return sorted(unique_urls)
```

I'm sure it doesn't cover all possible cases. But maybe you can extend it if that's not the case. I'm also not sure if you wanted to keep the 'http(s)://' parts. If yes, then just add them to the results.